# IOS: how to remove date in UIMONTHYEAR Pickerview

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am new for IOS,i was used [UIMonthYearPickerview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uimonthyearpicker) for select month and year and show in UITextfield.but its shows like **month/date(default 1)/year aka 8/1/14.** but i need only to show in selected month and year like **8/14**.so how i remove to show default date in textfields?

any help?

Comment: The source is there, why not just fix it the way you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, here is a method i can remove the date in UIMONTHYEAR PICKERVIEW

```
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didChangeDate:(NSDate *)newDate
```